# How can I use 'works with google assistant' logo in my products packaging?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home, google-smart-home, google-assistant

My products can be control and report to google. I want to use 'works with google assistant' logo in my products packaging. How can I get the permission to use it? I did not find the certification page.

Answer (score 1):

The ["Works with Hey Google" certification](https://developers.google.com/assistant/console/policies/general-policies?hl=en#works_with_hey_google_certification) on the Assistant policies page outlines the up-to-date guidance on how to use it.

> When users search for and buy devices labeled with the ‘Works with Hey Google’ badge, they should expect robust functionality and a safe, reliable, and seamless experience. Beyond the secondary user authentication policy above, developers must also meet the following requirements for device certification and use of the ‘Works with Hey Google’ badge:

Once you review the policies and meet every piece, which will probably involve a review of your smart home action in the Actions Console, you can visit the [Partner Marketing Hub](https://partnermarketinghub.withgoogle.com/brands/google-assistant/) to see the specifics of branding on your product including badges, colors, and typography.

[image]